# expanding button in css without needing absolute positioning

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an expanding css button.  I have made some progress but can't seem to get it to work unless I use absolute positioning.  Is there a way to make this type of button without needing it to be absolute positioned on a page.  Thanks for any help.  Below is what I have so far.

I want it to work without needing to be absolutely positioned on the page.

```css
.add-new-button {
  right: 250px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #1BA1FC;
  border-radius: 40px;
  transition: width 0.3s;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.add-new-button-icon {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 4;
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  transition: transform 0.2s;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.add-new-button-icon i {
  top: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 14px;
  position: relative;
}

.add-new-button:hover {
  width: 110px;
}

.add-new-button:hover .add-new-button-icon {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.add-new-button-label {
  width: 80px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif !important;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  opacity: 0;
}

.add-new-button:hover .add-new-button-label {
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="add-new-button">
  <div class="add-new-button-label">
    Add
  </div>
  <div class="add-new-button-icon">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems (to me) that your button doesn't need to have `position: fixed;`. All it need is some sufficient space to roll out.

```css
#container {
    border: 2px black solid;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    width: 200px;
}

.add-new-button {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #1BA1FC;
  border-radius: 40px;
  transition: width 0.3s;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.add-new-button-icon {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 4;
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  transition: transform 0.2s;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.add-new-button-icon i {
  top: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 14px;
  position: relative;
}

.add-new-button:hover {
  width: 110px;
}

.add-new-button:hover .add-new-button-icon {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.add-new-button-label {
  width: 80px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif !important;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  opacity: 0;
}

.add-new-button:hover .add-new-button-label {
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="container">
    <div class="add-new-button">
      <div class="add-new-button-label">
        Add
      </div>
      <div class="add-new-button-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Makes sense. Your solution works great!